# "too few template arguments" when using sizeof... in a template parameter list (MSVC 2017)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++14

The following minimal example does not build on current MSVC 2017 (19.16). It does build on MSVC 2015 and older versions of 2017 (19.14), GCC, Clang, and ICC. So I suspect it is a compiler bug. Is it valid? If not, why?

```
#include <array>
#include <utility>

template<int... Is>
auto foo(std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>)
{
    return std::array<int, unsigned(sizeof...(Is))>{ Is... };
}

std::array<int, 3> bar()
{
    return foo(std::make_integer_sequence<int, 3>());
}
```

Variants that do work:

- Putting `unsigned(sizeof...(Is))` in the parameter list as a defaulted parameter
- Replacing `unsigned(...)` with `static_cast<unsigned>(...)`
- Removing the cast (not a solution in the real world code, only in the minimal example)

Comment: Can't you use `std::size_t` instead of `unsigned` ?

Comment: As mentioned in parentheses, no I cannot.

Comment: Why do you cast a `size_t` to `unsigned` which is a template parameter of type `size_t`? And why do you need this needless cast in "real world code"?

Comment: The real world code has an unsigned template parameter

Comment: I still would drop the cast even in real world, the implicit conversion occuring then should be absolutely fine, too.

Comment: On the other hand: If real world code accepts sizes, `size_t` would be the appropriate type for the template parameter, too. If you *can* change it, I'd do so.

Comment: We had an issue with one of the compilers we use that failed if the cast wasn't there. I did try using `size_t` but the optimizer of another one of the compilers caused a gigantic performance drop (like, 20% or so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely a compiler bug. However, it seems to have been fixed. Builds here with Visual Studio 2019 (MSVC version 19.20.27508.1)…

Comment: I suspected as much. The 19.20 version on godbolt.org also fails though. And I can't upgrade to 2019.

Comment: Yes, it seems the version on godbolt is just barely not fresh enough. It definitely does compile on my machine here. I guess using `static_cast` should be a useable workaround for you?